# Container Registry TYPO3 not available

Tags: php, deployment, typo3, command-line-interface

At deployment getting the following exception when trying to invoke a typo3 cli command. `./typo3cms list`. At local env this does not occur

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception #1519978105: Container entry "TYPO3\CMS\Core\Console\CommandRegistry" is not available.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The occurs due that the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are not deployed to the machine were the command is executed.
In these file a configuration/bootstrap is setup which is needed to invoke these commands.

Comment: Thanks! That would have probably taken me a few hours to find out, it's exactly what was wrong with my Surf deployment setup. Instant solution!

Comment: Note: You only need `compser.json` files of the TYPO3 extensions, the root `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files are *not* required. Therefore, make sure to only exclude `/composer.json` during deployment, not all `composer.json` files in general.

Answer (score 1):

You probably excluded *all* files named `composer.json` in your deployment configuration.
Doing so excludes the desired root `composer.json`, but also `composer.json` from `EXT:core`, which you probably didn't intend to exclude.

Therefore, make sure to adapt your deployment to only exclude `/composer.json` instead of `composer.json` in general:

```
  exclude:
    - /composer.json
```

Background: The container entry `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Console\CommandRegistry` is defined by the service provider `TYPO3\CMS\Core\ServiceProvider` which is registered in `typo3/sysext/core/composer.json`:

```
"typo3/cms": {
    "Package": {
        "serviceProvider": "TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ServiceProvider"
    }
}
```

When the `composer.json` file is dropped, the service provider registration is unavailable and therefore the container entry will not be defined.